# how to update com.android.application plugin?

Tags: android

I'm getting this message:

```
Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version,
or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to
"a9d6c794295e89d95704157e2ed8fd55ffd2765c"
```

and:

```
C:\path\mobile\build.gradle
Error:(1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':mobile'.
Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

top build.gradel file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't know how to update that com.android.application plugin.

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file. Depending on your project setup, you may have more than one of these. The one that has `buildscript` in it is the one that we need to see.

Comment: I updated the question with the top build.gradelfile

Comment: There is a `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2` now, IIRC. Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: It worked. How and where do I know when this is updated?

Comment: See the answer that I just posted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, beta releases of the Gradle for Android plugin expire. AFAIK, that is not documented behavior. Right now, the only way that I know of to find out what the latest beta release is would be by monitoring http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system. It actually shows a `beta3`; I had thought that the latest was `beta2`.

Comment: 1.3.0-beta4 is available now. (I could not find where to see the "latest" gradle available from the link you provided .. where should I be navigating to (I missed that).

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: It's the release notes, just after the embedded video. There, it shows the latest as `beta3`.

Comment: ... but 1.3.0-beta4 is now available and DOES work when configuring gradle (beta3 was needed earlier)

Comment: @ErstwhileIII: Sorry, my previous comment wasn't questioning whether beta4 existed, but merely pointing out that the site only lists beta3. [I have asked for clarification on this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adt-dev/LlWu6vUqzDI/ZGOgL_f4_z0J).

Answer (score 19):

I just needed to change the line

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'`

to

`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'` in **top** `build.gradle`

I knew it was `alpha3` because of the last release note http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same problem.

I changed the gradle version from

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-rc1'
```

Since Android Studio is updated so from April 22 2016 it is the latest gradle version.

As of May 11 the stable gradle version is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Find latest version of the build system from [Android studio project site][1]

[1]: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system and update classpath accordingly. As of 2016/6/23, it is *2.2.0-alpha4*. So, make it `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4`on *build.gradle* file.