# Android Studio plugin is too old

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I was syncing fine and then suddenly when I tried to run a test on a device from Android Studio I started getting the error:

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable ...
```

I've looked around and I found from the gradle website that the latest version is 2.10, I tried adding that to my dependencies with no luck.  I've tried various version numbers with various errors like the following:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1
Searched in the following locations ...
```

I understand from all the searching I've done that its clearly a wrong version of gradle - but what IS the current version label I should be using, and how do I know it is installed on my machine ? I've always kept Android Studio updated.

So I currently have in the build.gradle:

```
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: did you check the (gradle-wrapper.properties file) -- https://guides.codepath.com/android/Getting-Started-with-Gradle

Comment: could you tell me what version of Android Studio are you use?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

UPDATED (28/03/2017):

2.4.0-alpha3 is the latest release

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.4.0-alpha3'
```

Check https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.android.tools.build.gradle/view for the latest gradle versions.

---

2.0.0-alpha1 is on the Canary channel and apparently these releases come with an expiry date. 2.0.0-alpha3 is the latest release. Switch to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
```

and you should be fine. Keep checking http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system to know the latest releases.

You might run into some Dex error. I had to do Build > Clean Project once to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks very much - I haven't read the entire link, but does it detail the difference between these releases? Ie, what is Canary channel etc ?

Answer (score 18):

#### Change your existing configuration with this

1. In your project view, select `Gradle Scripts`
2. Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`
3. Change this line:

   ```
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
   ```

with

```
     distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

4. Go to build.gradle (Project: your_app_name)
5. Change this line

   ```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha1'
   ```

to this

```
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

6. Don't click `Sync Now`
7. From menu choose `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart...`
8. Choose first option: `Invalidate and Restart`

Android Studio would restart. After this, it should work normally

Hope it help

Answer (score 7):

Now   `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3` is old
 use  this

```
 com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2
```

Answer (score 4):

If your having trouble getting the plugin to resolve.  Check that your including `jcenter()` (Jcenter) in your `repositories` for the `buildscript`.  Google does not publish the plugin to `mavenCentral()` (Maven Central).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
    }
}
```

As others have mentioned the latest ATM is `2.0.0-alpha3` but that could change at any time.  Here is the source of truth on the latest available version:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle

As for the actual error here is the best answer is in is link. TLDR, undocumented feature of the non release plugins is they expire and you have to update.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293869/873237

Answer (score 0):

Just solved by doing the following steps:

1 - Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Replace

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

with

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```

2 - Open build.gradle (Project: app_name)

Replace

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```